# Hiding data that's currently in an element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table `posts` that I display info from with the following query:

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts
```

I then put all of these results into HTML elements like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="result" id="' . $post_id . '"></div>';
?>
```

I don't want the `$post_id` to be public (since it's being put into id), but I also need to be able to get the post_id when someone clicks the `.result` div as I use it to show more data when clicked on through JavaScript and PHP:

```
$(document).on("click", ".result", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_more_info.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { post_id: $(this).attr('id') },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I keep the post_id hidden from the public, but also get it when someone clicks on the `.result` element?

Comment: But isn't it 'the public' that'll be clicking on the element to show that information? And, regardless, security through obbscurity is no kind of security. Use a log-in mechanism to allow the information to be accessed appropriately.

Comment: Why don't you want the `post_id` to be "pubic"?  What are you worried about?

Comment: @RocketHazmat If there's way to hide it, I want to be able to hide it. It's not exactly a security issue, but rather an aesthetics issue (it just seems wrong to me to be doing it this way).

Comment: Aesthetics?  What do you mean?  Personally I use `data-postid="123"`.  I don't think that's "ugly".

Comment: a classname is nothing a user sees

Answer (score 0):

You can keep array of Id's in session variable and choose it on server side based on the position of clicked div in some general parent (e.g. AJAX sends the position of generated div and you will decide on server, which id it is), if you really think it worth it. You will then need no ids.